# StructureMap DI does not register implementations from nuget package

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, visual-studio-2017, structuremap

I been trying to understand this problem for the most part of the last two days, 
it seems that when using a nuget package that utilize a .net core package with
a StructurMap Registry the stuff in the registry never gets into the container of the app. here is the code of the nuget package:

```
public class SomeRegistry : Registry
{
    public SomeRegistry()
    {
        this.For<ILogger>().Use<Logger>();
    }
}
```

and here is the startup lookup for the registries:

```
 public virtual void ConfigureContainer(Registry registry)
    {


        registry.Scan(
            c =>
            {
                c.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
                c.LookForRegistries();
            });

        //this is just for testing 
        var con = new Container(registry);
        con.GetInstance<SomeDLL.ILogger>();//this will fail with "No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type" 
    }
```

im using .net core traget framework 2.1

structureMap.AspNetCore 1.4.0

visual studio 2017

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well problem solved, it seems that

```
 c.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
```

scans only the app folder ( as the name suggested ) but on .net core the nuget 
packages dont get copy to app folder ( they are loaded to memory from cache folder )

solution is to get the assemblies our self and load them to  assembly scanner like so:

```
var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(assembly => assembly.GetTypes()
            .Any(t => t != typeof(Registry) && typeof(Registry).IsAssignableFrom(t))).ToList();

        registry.Scan(
            c =>
            {
                assemblies.ForEach(a => c.Assembly(a));
                c.LookForRegistries();
            });
```

Comment: In my case, my Registry class was in the my console application, so by simply calling `c.AssembliesAndExecutablesFromApplicationBaseDirectory()` instead of `c.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory()`, StructureMap was able to find it.